# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Tags: php

Подскажите если сделать запрос например index.php?root 
файл index.php содержит следующий код:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == root) { require 'form.php'; }
?>
```

Все работает отлично!
Но далее если, например сделать запрос index.php?root434343 или index.php?rom или любой другой которой нет соответствия в коде?
Как если такое значение отсутствует в коде отловить его
и вывести например: 
echo "bla bla bla";

Comment: Это вы так роутинг пытаетесь имитировать?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь конструкцией `switch-case`. В кейсах нужные переменные, в дефолте вывести `echo "bla bla bla";`

Answer (score 0):

Проверяем, задана ли вообще `QUERY_STRING`. Если да, сравниваем с правильной и производим нужные действия.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == root)
        require 'form.php';
    else
        echo "blah blah blah";
}
?>
```

Comment: а если их несколько
`if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == root3) { require 'form4.php'; }`
`if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == root5) { require 'form8.php'; }`

Comment: проверяйте все, если ни одна не подошла - пишите "бла-бла"

Comment: Вам нужен оператор `elseif` =)